# C# LINQ Query with group by, having and where clause invalid

Tags: c#, sql, linq, telerik

I have the following Linq queries which are getting the error below. My question is how can I use the T_EquipmentCompetency.Competency in a where clause but not have it in the group by or select list. I am fairly new to LINQ queries. Is there something that I am missing here?

```
using (EntitiesModel dbContext = new EntitiesModel())
        {
            var competencyForMachine = (from eq in dbContext.T_Equipmentcompetencies
                where eq.MachineId == machineId
                select eq.CompetencyId);

            var competencyForEmployees = (from sm in dbContext.T_OHS_Skillsmatrices
                join em in dbContext.T_Employees on sm.EmployeeID equals em.EmployeeID
                where competencyForMachine.Contains(sm.CompentencyID)
                group sm by new {sm.EmployeeID,em.FirstNameSTR,em.LastNameSTR} into g
                where g.Count() == competencyForMachine.Count()
                select new {g.Key.EmployeeID, g.Key.FirstNameSTR,g.Key.LastNameSTR});

            foreach(var employee in competencyForEmployees)
            {  
                RadMenuItem employeeItem = new RadMenuItem { Text= employee.FirstNameSTR + " " + employee.LastNameSTR, Value = employee.EmployeeID.ToString()};
                Item.Items.Add(employeeItem);
            }
        }
```

This is the error I am getting

```
Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.sql.SQLException: Column 
'dbo.T_EquipmentCompetency.CompetencyId' is invalid in the select list 
because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

The sql I am trying to emulate  works in SQL Server

```
declare @MachineId int = 1                      
select  sm.EmployeeID,em.FirstNameSTR,em.LastNameSTR 
from    T_OHS_SkillsMatrix sm
inner join T_Employees em on sm.EmployeeID = em.employeeId  
where sm.CompentencyID in  (    select  CompetencyID
                            from    T_EquipmentCompetency
                            where   MachineId = @machineId  
                        )
group by sm.EmployeeID,em.FirstNameSTR,em.LastNameSTR
having count(*) =  (select count(*) from T_EquipmentCompetency where MachineId = @MachineId)
```

Comment: I have fixed the spelling mistake outlined below but I am still having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

you got it mispelled

```
select eq.CompetencyId   --- different spelling

sm.CompentencyID
```

while in sql sql server

```
where sm.CompentencyID in  (    select  CompentencyID
```

Comment: Thanks I have corrected the spelling error. The problem still exists and the question remains. I am still getting results in sql server but the above error in LINQ C#

Comment: so what's the error now? can you post your updated script

Comment: The error is the same. I have edited the spelling mistake in the SQL Server script. Obviously I have 2 different spellings between sm and eq in the LINQ queries but they reflect the database table columns.